# Angular Select Adding undefined option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this `tempScale` object defined in my controller:

```
$scope.tempScale = {
    scaleType : [],
    deviations : [],
    intervals : 0
};
```

Which connects to my html:

```
<select id="scales" ng-model="tempScale.scaleType" class="form-control">
    <option value="Manually Calculated" ng-selected="true">Manually Calculated</option>
    <option value="Automatically Calculated">Automatically Calculated</option>
</select>
```

I added in the `ng-selected=true` so that manually calculated would be the first and selected option (basically a default option 1), however, when I run the page, my HTML looks like:

```
<select id="scales" ng-model="tempScale.scaleType" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
    <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
    <option value="Manually Calculated" ng-selected="true" selected="selected">Manually Calculated</option>
    <option value="Automatically Calculated">Automatically Calculated</option>
</select>
```

Why are those ng classes appearing on load, and where is this undefined option value coming from? It's not a loop, so I'm baffled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `ng-selected`. Set the model from the controller as `$scope.tempScale.scaleType='Manually Calculated';`.

> One cannot set a default selected item when using ng-model directive with select element. The select element is bind to model field, which data is undefined. What value select should display? Yes, undefined. You try to pass data via markup, it is not an Angular way.
>   Just keep your data in JS model, not in HTML markup.[[Ref](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1019)]

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/JrzDAz6pTQTrTax1SFQO?p=preview)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know ng-model more or less canceled out the default selected item. Thank you.